# NIntegrate with and without MaxRecursion

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

Ran a mathematica code using NIntegrate containing an integration over spherical and normal bessel functions. 
1.Would the answer in the two cases change if I use MaxRecursion with some number of recursions and don't use it?
2. And also will it matter if I use the global adaptive strategy?
3. In case I want to exclude singularity points for x variable, would I use {x,a,b,c,d} where a and b are singular points and c and d are integration limits.

Comment: Show your work as a example. Will help get your answer faster.

Comment: You'll have better luck on the [mathematica stack exchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).